# Proper way to handle multiple "pages" in meteor

Tags: meteor

What is the "formal" way of handling multiple "pages" in meteor? I say "pages" I've seen people do it a couple of different ways. I've seen people create actual full pages, (index.html, about.html, contact.html) and then when links are clicked, you'd write a route to render those pages. But I've also seen people essentially put the code for each of those pages inside `<template>` tags and then do nifty show/hide type stuff based of what they've clicked, login credentials, etc.

Comment: Probably iron-router?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways to handle multiple pages in meteor

### [1.iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)

using iron router you can create a layout template and inject all other templates inside it using `{{> yield}}`. Check the [iron-router guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md) to know more about layout template.

### [2.{{> Template.dynamic}}](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)

if you do not want to add iron-router you can use `{{> Template.dynamic}}` to achieve the same.

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="index">Home</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="about">About</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</li>
  </ul>
  {{> Template.dynamic template=template_name }}
</body>
```

`template_name` can be changed reactively using a template helper

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Session.setDefault("templateName", "index")
});

Template.body.helpers({
  template_name: function(){
    return Session.get("templateName")
  }
});

Template.body.events({
  "click .home": function() {
    Session.set("templateName", "index");
  },
  "click .about": function() {
     Session.set("templateName", "about");
  }
  // ..
});
```

If the Session returns "about" then,
`{{> Template.dynamic template="about"}}` which is equivalent to `{{> about}}`.

Comment: Thanks, seems like the IronRouter is going to be the easiest/best route for me. Pun intended.

Comment: Good answer. I especially recommend the iron-router. It's the one used in the (advanced)Todo-list and LocalMarket examples.

Comment: @E.Gunyar yes iron-router is the most common routing library in meteor applications but if the app is very small and we don't want to deal with one more library then `dynamic template` is a one easy alternative.