# Dynamically insert templates: Variable is correct but template doesnt get inserted

Tags: meteor

I am trying to insert various templates depending on which button is clicked. For this I created an event that sets a session variable with the id of the button.

```
   'click .task-option-button': function (e) {
      var template = e.target.id;
      Session.set('addTaskTemplate', template);
      console.log(template);
    }
```

and a helper that returns the session variable

```
addTaskTemplate: function () {
  var taskTemplate = Session.get('addTaskTemplate');
  return taskTemplate;
},
```

and then the template gets inserted like this

```
{{> Template.dynamic template= "{{addTaskTemplate}}"" }}
```

However, clicking the button doesn't add the template. When I put

```
{{> Template.dynamic template= "SomeStaticTemplate" }}
```

it works. Also using {{addTaskTemplate}} as a normal variable in `<p></p>` tags works and returns the id of the button as a string. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{> Template.dynamic template= addTaskTemplate }}` will do. Just remove the `{{ }}` brackets.

Comment: What the hell...I don't know why I didn't try that out, but then why the hell would it work differently than literally every other variable in Meteor?... Thank you, it solved the problem.

Comment: `{{> Template.dynamic template = template}}` is already inside `{{ }}` so you do not have to include another `{{ }}`. here is an example for dynamic template http://stackoverflow.com/a/26945391/2751392

Comment: I have been looking for days on how to do this. Thanks!