# Meteor.Router vs Iron Router

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I want to create a multi-page Meteor web and mobile application. I am therefore looking for routing services.

From [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26945391/2317532), I gathered [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) is what I am looking for. But many tutorials also mention `Meteor.Router`

#### What are the differences (if any) between Iron Router and `Meteor.Router`?

Comment: I went for iron router and I am satisfied with it. Reason why I went for iron router is because of the community support for it. I don't know the deep down details of iron router much but for me going for a package that is backed by the community is really important when choosing which package to go for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iron:router` has been the de facto standard routing solution for Meteor for over a year now, you should definitely use it, it's probably the most downloaded atmosphere package.

Please note however that the project has not been updated for several months and another router ([FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router)) package emerged, focusing only on client-side routing and managing subscriptions, it takes a different approach than `iron:router` by making the routing code non-reactive by default.

Meteor.Router is a [deprecated](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/iron-router-update/) package that used to be maintained by one of the two main contributors to `iron:router`, tutorials mentioning this are clearly outdated.

The [`iron:router` guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md) is a recommended reading to understand some advanced concepts like server-side and client-side routing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've managed to find a reference now and linked it.

Comment: The iron:router guide has been moved to https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer and added a note about the emergence of `meteorhacks:flow-router`